# FABridge question

Tags: ajax, apache-flex

If i create a table in JQuery or any other Ajax framework, can i completely pass the table to flex with the same look and feel... using FABridge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass the data, but not the 'look and feel'. Youll have to build the datagrid inside flex using either actionscript or javascript in FABridge.